# .htaccess rewriting a URL - Change WordPress URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite my WordPress post's URL which is currently:

```
http://example.com/posts/titleofpost
```

to

```
http://example.com/titleofpost
```

What am I doing wrong by chance?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^posts/(.+)$   title=$1   [L]
```

I have a feeling that the `title=$1` is wrong, and should be some different expression? What could this expression be?

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule   ^posts/(.+)$   $1   [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And this would work if I had numbers in my post url from the start?

Comment: Any symbol will be ok , including numbers

Comment: @Raymond Pittman If you are satisfied with the answer, you might consider [**accepting**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it.